# Search result pagination laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, search, pagination

My pagination works on the first page correctly. It displays correctly 2 names. When I want to see the other results on the next pages, it will display nothing with my current code. When I make an static array:

```
 $searchResults = [
            'item1',
            'item2',
            'item3',
            'item4',
            'item5',
            ];
```

It will display the array correctly over different pages.
When I make an array from my sql query, it displays nothing on the next pages.
I used var_dump and on the second page, I didn't see anything of my created array.

this is my controller code:

```
public function zoekdocument(Request $request) //voor het zoeken van software
{

$zoekdocument = \Request::get('zoekdocument');

$searchResult = array();

$searchdoc = \DB::table('visits')->where('title', 'LIKE', '%' . $zoekdocument . '%')->paginate();

foreach($searchdoc as $searchdocument){ 

    $filedir = $searchdocument->pagename; //wordt gedurende loop tot die finisht in de array gezet.

    $searchResult[] = $filedir; //dat wordt hier gedaan.
}

    $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();

    $page = $request->has('page') ? $request->get('page') : 1;

    //Create a new Laravel collection from the array data
    $collection = new Collection($searchResult);

    $perPage = 2;

   $currentPageSearchResults = $collection-> slice (($currentPage -1) * $perPage, $perPage)->all();
    //Create our paginator and pass it to the view
    $paginatedSearchResults= new 

LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageSearchResults, count($collection), $perPage, $page, ['path'  => $request->url(),'query' => $request->query(),

return view('Documentatie.result', ['results' => $paginatedSearchResults])->with('zoekdocument', $zoekdocument);
```

This is my view code:

```
@section('content')

<!-- Striped rows -->
<div class="panel panel-flat">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h5 class="panel-title text-center">Documentatie overzicht resultaat</h5>
    <div class="heading-elements">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="text-center">
    <h2>Zoekresultaat van: <b><i>{{$zoekdocument}}</b></i></h5>
    </div>  

 @foreach ($results as $result)
        <p>{{ $result }}</p>
    @endforeach

    <?php echo $results->render(); ?>




@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed in my code, paginate() for get() and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code should fix the error by displaying the pagination links as per the laravel documentation:

```
{{ $users->links() }}
```

In the place of

```
<?php echo $results->render(); ?>
```

Here is the documentation link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/pagination
Let me know if that works and if not I will try to help find a solution.

Comment: It doesn't work. Its weird, when I do the same with a static array, it works. I think it it goes wrong by my sql query. my query check what agree with the searched word and make an array. For example: keyword = "te" and the query is searching in the database for names with "te". after that, it will put it in the array by a loop. when I click on the next page, the array is empty.